# "Which policies might impact X in country Y" on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Suppose I am interested in evaluating the impact of [a particular public program] on [some outcome X] in [country Y], say the impact of [Adult Education and Family Literacy Act spendings] on [adult literacy] in [the US].

In an attempt to control for confounding factors, I am interested in learning about other public programs that might also influence outcome [X].

Would a question like "What are public policies that might impact [X] in country [Y]?" be on topic here?

If not, do you think it would be on another SE site?

Answer (score 1):

So long as X is limited*  in scope and about government policy, you should be fine. Narrowing down to a single or a few countries also helps keep the scope limited.

*your example is good, something broad like [military decisions] on [foreign policy] might be vague and broad.